# Can't get all contacts when use ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone

Tags: android, contacts

Below is the code I used to get all contacts from phone.

```
     public static ArrayList<Recipient> getAllRecipient(Context context) {

        ArrayList<Recipient> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            try {
                final int displayNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
                final int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                final int typeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
                final int uriIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI);

                String displayName, number, uri;
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    int type = cursor.getInt(typeIndex);
                    if (type == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        displayName = cursor.getString(displayNameIndex);
                        number = cursor.getString(numberIndex);
                        number = number.replaceAll("[^0-9+]+", "");//remove all special character and space, just keep digit number and "+"
                        uri = cursor.getString(uriIndex);
                        Recipient recipient = new Recipient(displayName, number, uri);
                        contacts.add(recipient);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogUtil.debug("can't get recipient: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return contacts;
    }
```

I got feedback from many users , they can not get full contacts in their phones, show almost contacts but missed some contacts.

Is there any problem with above code ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
while (phones.moveToNext())
{


String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));


String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

}
phones.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Phone.CONTENT_URI` includes all Phone entries of the device. If a contact does not have some phone you are not going to get any information about it.
If contacts is what you are after, you should query the [ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_URI).

Keep in mind that contacts and phone are two separate things for Android. Not all contacts have phone numbers and you would have to query the numbers separately.

Comment: then how do you get number?